# Home page in MVC app is not correctly routed with IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

I deployed an MVC app in Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5 (Integrated Mode). The first page that the browser should show if I enter the address (http://192.168.3.5:2011/) is a Login page. The thing is that instead I found that it executes the first ActionResult returner method found in the controller that is in the top of a allegued alphabetically ordered list ???. On the other hand if I type http://192.168.3.5:2011/Default.aspx everything goes correct; it shows the Login page. My routing table in the Global.asax is defined as:

```
   public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
   {
       public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
       {
          routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

          routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", 
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
             new { controller = "Login", action = "Login", id = "" } 
          );
       }

       protected void Application_Start()
       {
           RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
       }
   }
```

The outcome that I get is that it redirects to the following address: http://192.168.3.5:2011/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2f and then configuration error is thrown:

```
<providers>
         <clear />
         <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" applicationName="/" />
</providers>
```

There is a LogOn method, which is the first one declared in the Account Controller, which is the first controller alphabeticaly ordered.

In IIS 6.0 classic mode works fine but not in IIS 7.5 (Integrated mode). This is driving me crazy.

Thank you for your help.

Regards.

Comment: Please provide details (at least name and controller) on the action that is being executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear to me that authentication is configured in the one case and not in the other.  The Account/Logon has the return URL parameter which is typically provided due to a redirect when the original request isn't authenticated.

Comment: What should I change then? Sorry I did not understand the answer :-( By the way, I have a link in other place of the app and I also get the same error.

Comment: Thanks Jared and Max for your help. At the end it was an authentication issue. I changed in the IIS from Form to Windows and tadà... it worked! I still do not understand very well what happened.

Answer (score 0):

You can try defining id as a UrlParameter.Optional:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Login", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Comment: It seems I cannot access the UrlParameter class. I am working with V2 of the framework.

Comment: UrlParameter was introduced in mvc2, it belongs to the namespace System.Web.Mvc

Comment: Maybe it is part of MVC2 but does it corresponde to NET Framework V2? The Visual Studio cannot find it... :-(

Comment: The app is within the DefaultAppPool which runs version 2.0 of the NET Framework although I develop the app with Visual Web Developer 2008 targetting 3.5 version.